# What are X and Y relative to?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The `getpos` console command returns the x, y, or z coordinate of the target. Prefixing it with `player.` targets the player. E.g., the game may return:

> GetPos: X >> 2055.76

Unlike the `getpos` console command, the `setpos` console command provides no feedback, instead silently setting the position of the target, fully noticeable once the game is unpaused (which requires closing the console). Here's an example: `player.setpos x 2055.76`.

What are X and Y relative to? E.g., is a greater X value more north?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Northward: Y (positive).
- Southward: Y negative.
- Eastward: X (positive).
- Westward: X negative

Z (positive) is higher (& Z negative is lower).

0 seems to be the center of the cell, probably predetermined by the map developer. In the case of Helgen Keep, it is outside of the traversable map area, south of and higher than a staircase.